# error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maps, visual-studio-2017

I found the Xamarin.Forms [Map Control sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/). I downloaded it, but am unable to build it for Android with Visual Studio 2017 RC4. I'm getting build errors.

The first one is:

> WorkingWithMaps\Android\Resources\Resource.designer.cs(12,36,12,61): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

Does someone know how to resolve this error? It builds on iOS without issue.

Thank you.